# What is the proper way to store a global connection in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

I have the following file that acts as the access point to my DB from my API endpoints. What is the proper way to maintain a single connection (or a connection pool?) for the life of the server?

```
(ns my-api.repository
  (:require [clojure.java.jdbc :as sql]))

(defn some-query
  (sql/with-connection (System/getenv "DATABASE_URL")
    (sql/with-query-results results
      ;; You get the picture
      )))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the `DATABASE_URL` is stored, if you use `with-connection` macro for single connection. you can use [c3p0](http://sourceforge.net/projects/c3p0) library for connection pool:

```
(defn pooled-spec
  "return pooled conn spec.
   Usage:
     (def pooled-db (pooled-spec db-spec))
     (with-connection pooled-db ...)"
  [{:keys [classname subprotocol subname user password] :as other-spec}]
  (let [cpds (doto (ComboPooledDataSource.)
               (.setDriverClass classname)
               (.setJdbcUrl (str "jdbc:" subprotocol ":" subname))
               (.setUser user)
               (.setPassword password))]
    {:datasource cpds}))
```

Answer (score 3):

I also recommend c3p0.
[Clojure connection pooling](http://clojure-doc.org/articles/ecosystem/java_jdbc/connection_pooling.html)
provides a succinct introduction to how to configure `clojure.java.jdbc` with c3p0.

Answer (score 2):

[jdbc-pool](https://github.com/ToBeReplaced/jdbc-pool) simplifies the process of using C3P0 with clojure.java.jdbc.  I created the library specifically (and only) for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think with-connection holds anything open.  Doc nor source suggest it, and in 2.3 I was able to confirm it by inspecting *db* after running queries.  The source looks like this:

```
(defn with-connection*
  "Evaluates func in the context of a new connection to a database then
  closes the connection."
  [db-spec func]
  (with-open [^java.sql.Connection con (get-connection db-spec)]
    (binding [*db* (assoc *db* :connection con :level 0 :rollback (atom false))]
      (func))))
```

Connection pooling may be useful in lazily creating them, but that doesn't hold them open.  Making the connection settable seems to be necessary.  However the latest API emphasizes just creating the connection and passing it into each call.  While still ALPHA, this looks like the future for this library (and is still compatible with connection pooling).  From the library's wiki:

```
(require '[clojure.java.jdbc :as j]
     '[clojure.java.jdbc.sql :as s])

(def mysql-db {:subprotocol "mysql"
               :subname "//127.0.0.1:3306/clojure_test"
               :user "clojure_test"
               :password "clojure_test"})

(j/insert! mysql-db :fruit
  {:name "Apple" :appearance "rosy" :cost 24}
  {:name "Orange" :appearance "round" :cost 49})
```